# Why is the "/fill . . . replace" command not working in Bedrock Edition anymore?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

The last time I played Minecraft I was able to use the command:

```
/fill 582 38 -566 600 45 -577 air 0 replace reinforced_deepslate
```

Now it wants me to use `/fill . . . air [replace` instead of: `. . . air 0 replace. . .`

I used the last one but it returned an error:

> "syntax error: Unexpected /fill 582 38 -566 600 45 -577 air 0 >>replace<< reinforced_deepslate

Comment: Command functions tend to change in Minecraft versions. I'm not really sure how we can properly answer why, except that the developers deem it necessary for whatever reason: functionality, optimization, ease-of-use, &c.

Comment: While this question might not be asked in a an optimal way, it asks a very important question, one that a lot of other players might have, too. Making a breaking change like this causes confusion for anyone not reading the update logs and keeping up with command changes, not unlike the recent `execute` change: All the old information on this is outdated and it will take some time for the available information to be updated. This question helps with the update process.

Comment: I agree that this isn't really asking "why the command was changed to work this way" but rather "why isn't this command working" with the intent to get a working command as @Plagiatus seems to have answered.

Comment: @TimmyJim ... but the question explicitly acknowledges the new syntax. That makes it clear that they don't need help debugging their command (because if they did they wouldn't mention the syntax it wanted them to use), and are instead asking why the change was made. And of course we now have moderator supervotes where the non-mod reviewers were unanimously in favor of closing.

Comment: @pppery sorry, but I disagree. I also waited two days before casting a vote, with the intention of letting the community vote first 
 Some members of the community skipped the review task, which to me indicates they were indifferent on the question. As it is now, this question seems appropriate enough to me.  The community still has the ability to close if they wish.

Comment: @pppery I disagree, too. They say "it wants me to use" and then provide a syntactically wrong answer, because that's what the game produces if you use the autocomplete feature. Thus their request seems to be "help me get this command working again" and not "why has the game changed?"

Answer (score 4):

In 1.19.70 a big change for blocks happened:

## Minecraft switched from numeric data to string block states.

*Quick Fix:* **If you have a block data of `0`, just replace it with `[]`**

### What are block states?

Block states describe the state(s) that a block can be in, and can define and influence how it appears or behaves.

They appear in the form of `["type":<state>]` and go in place of where the block data used to go. State can be one of the following three data types:

- a Boolean, so `true` or `false`, for example `"button_pressed_bit":false` for buttons
- an Integer, so a whole number, for example `"age":2` for crops
- a String, for example `"color":"white"` for glass *(notice how only the string value type is surrounded by `"`)*

#### Examples

```
setblock ~~~ stained_glass["color":"green"]
```

You can also combine multiple block states by separating them through a comma:

```
setblock ~~~ wood["pillar_axis":"z","stripped_bit":true,"wood_type":"spruce"]
```

### Current issues

Unfortunately at the time of writing there are various usability issues that prevent this feature from being as good as it can be. Here are the pitfalls:

#### Autocomplete

The game does not provide proper auto-complete like in Java, so you still have to refer to the **[List of Block States](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_states)** manually. But here is to hoping it will be fixed sooner than later.

It also autocompletes just the `[`, but not the closing one, so it leads to issues like OP describes, where you end up with `[replace` instead, which doesn't make any sense at all.

#### Testing for blocks

Detection commands involving blocks (such as `/testforblock` or `/execute if block`) need to have ALL the block states listed and defined in order for it to work (my guess is that it's because they might use their default value if not specified, but I haven't confirmed this). An example of what to do and what not to do is below:

❌ this won't necessarily work the way you want it to:

```
execute if block ~~~ stone_button["button_pressed_bit":true]
```

✅ what to do instead:

```
execute if block ~~~ stone_button["button_pressed_bit":true,"facing_direction":1]
```

#### Placement and requirement inconsistency

Block states have default values, so it should not be necessary to include them every time. And in Java this is solved by attaching the block states directly to the block instead of making it its own argument. This generally is not too big of an issue, can just be a bit annoying due to how inconsistent it is.

So, while you can leave it out in some places, you have to include it in others, even if left empty. For example in `fill ... replace` you NEED to include the block state as it's own argument.

```
fill ... air [] replace reinforced_deepslate
```

### Why the change?

Java has them, too, and while it's more work to type it out, it's considerably more readable for humans and thus easier to work with for mapmakers in general.